# Matlab reading serial without pausing

Tags: matlab, serialization

I'm using fscanf to read data from a constant stream of information, coming from a sensor connected to an arduino, and to plot it in a real time graph.

The problem is, matlab takes too long to plot the live information, and this is because fscanf reads the serial information, and the next call to fscanf reads the next serial data, not the one currently being displayed.

I would like to know how do I read the *latest* information received from the serial port, instead of the *next* one. Any ideas on how to make the readings feel more "real-time" would be very helpful. Here's my code:

```
clear;
yThresh = 2.5;
delete(instrfindall);
s = serial('COM7', 'BaudRate', 57600);
fopen(s);

arq = fopen('dados.txt', 'w');


i = 1; 
while ~feof(arq)  %end of file


    a(i, 1:3) = fscanf(s, '%f%f%f')

    xValMax = i+20;
    xValMin = max(1,i-20);

    subplot(3,1,1);
    plot( max(1,i-20):length(a(:,1)) , a(max(1,i-20):length(a(:,1)),1) );
    title('AcelX','fontsize',13,'fontweight','bold');
    xlabel('Tempo','fontsize',10,'fontweight','bold');
    ylabel('AcelX','fontsize',10,'fontweight','bold');
    axis([xValMin xValMax -yThresh yThresh])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A few comments/suggestions: 
 
1) One thing that is missing from your code is an update of the index `i` at the end of your `while` loop. 
2) Consider pre-allocating space for the "plot buffer" `a` and using it as a circular buffer to speed up execution (as it is `a` keeps growing in size indefinitely). 
3) Try putting `drawnow` at the end of the loop. 
4) Try doing `set(s, 'InputBufferSize', 3)` before opening the serial port.

 
Hope these help.

Answer (score 0):

There's an awful lot more happening in your loop than needs to be - it is considerably quicker to plot once then update the data, rather than tearing down the plot and creating a new one every time.

Here's an idea for a more efficient arrangement (composed in browser, may contain errors):

```
clear;
yThresh = 2.5;
delete(instrfindall);
s = serial('COM7', 'BaudRate', 57600);
fopen(s);

arq = fopen('dados.txt', 'w');

a = NaN(1,20);
x = -18:1;

subplot(3,1,1);
hline = plot(x, a);
haxes = gca;
title('AcelX','fontsize',13,'fontweight','bold');
xlabel('Tempo','fontsize',10,'fontweight','bold');
ylabel('AcelX','fontsize',10,'fontweight','bold');
axis([1 3 -yThresh yThresh]);

while ~feof(arq)  %end of file
    newdata = fscanf(s, '%f%f%f');
    a = [a(2:end) newdata(1)];
    x = x + 1;
    % presumably you want to capture the data to that file at some point too?

    set(hline, 'XData', x, 'YData', a);
    xlim(haxes, [max(1,x(1)) x(end)]); 
end
```

For maximum update speed you might save a little more time by cheating the x axis - instead of changing the x data and axes limits each time, leave them untouched and just change the the tick labels (Or just forego the tick labels entirely, leaving nothing to update but the y data).